# Enable Visual Studio 2012 javascript syntax highlighting/intellisense for custom file extension

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a project that uses javascript in some files which have custom file extensions (.js.template).  I'd like to use the code completion/highlighting that Visual Studio comes with when editing these files, but there doesn't seem to be an option to apply Javascript editing to files that don't end in .js.

I have tried **Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension** then adding the extension **template** and assigning it to various editors available (including Script Editor and HTML Editor) but it doesn't seem to enable any of the Javascript code highlighting or intellisense. There doesn't seem to be a Javascript Editor available.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 **Express**

Any ideas?